# My st.show on stack cannot be display for some reason

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My problem on my code is when i run it, it says the error no matching function call to stack::show() which i have. i dont know whats causing the error, did some research that it should be on the public class which already there.

I used switch case 1 is to input 2nd is to show or to display the user inputs which I cant call out using st.show();

```
    private:
        int MAX;
        int top;
        string *arr_q;
    
    public:
        Stack (int size)
        {
            MAX=size;
            top=-1;
            arr_q=new string[MAX];
        }
        void push(string subs)
        {
        if ((top+1)==MAX)
            cout << "Stack Overflow..." << endl;
        top=top+1;
        arr_q[top]=subs;
        }
    
        void show(int lim)
        {
        int i = lim;
        cout<<"Stack contains --"<<endl;
        for (int ctr=i; ctr>=0; ctr--)
        {
            if (ctr==i)
                cout<<"\t\t"<<arr_q[ctr]<<"<--Top of Stack"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"\t\t"<<arr_q[ctr]<<endl;
        }
        }
    };
    
    case 2: {
    st.show();
    break;
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Comment: So as @Paul says, your `show` method has a parameter `lim`, but when you call the method you do not supply a parameter. That is the reason for the error. You should think carefully about the reason you added a parameter to `show`. It seems to me that it should not be there.

Comment: based on my professor, we should add parameter so the code know that if the stacks is full or not. so I added lim to know if its full

Comment: That's something your `Stack` class should keep track of itself (and I think that's probably what he meant).

Comment: @OtakuSensei I think you have misunderstood your professor. The stack is full if `top == MAX` (I think) you don't need a parameter in `show` to tell you that.

Comment: @OtakuSensei But in any case, if you are sure that the parameter should be there, then you must use a parameter when you call `show`. The fact that you didn't do that indicates that the parameter doesn't make much sense.

Comment: im sorry, i use lim to know if the stack is full and have a value or variables inside it will display it even if its not full

Comment: @OtakuSensei How does `lim` tell you if the stack is full?

Comment: i added the st.show(lim); but the error changes to not declared

Comment: @OtakuSensei Of course. What do you think `lim` is?

Comment: @OtakuSensei If you have a parameter to a function then when you call that function you have to give that parameter a value. The fact that you can't do that indicates that the parameter makes no sense to you. It doesn't make any sense to me either. The code I have written in the answer below does everything that you want (I think) and doesn't use a parameter. But if your professor told you that you must use a parameter, then the only person who can really help you is your professor.

Comment: thank you so much for helping, i ask him whats the parameter for and she said that we used parameter because in our code we only ask 1 time and the code will go to menu then if we want to display it it will display it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that your `show` function has a parameter but when you call it there is no parameter.

Seems reasonably likely that `show` should be written without a parameter. Like this

```
void show()
{
    cout<<"Stack contains --"<<endl;
    for (int ctr=top; ctr>=0; ctr--)
    {
        if (ctr==top)
            cout<<"\t\t"<<arr_q[ctr]<<"<--Top of Stack"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"\t\t"<<arr_q[ctr]<<endl;
    }
}
```